# Is the Virtual File System (VFS) a program or is it just an interface?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am trying to understand what the VFS is in Linux, the following diagram represents the VFS:

[image]

What I am not sure about is whether the VFS is a program that the Application talks to and then the VFS talks to the appropriate file system driver, or is the VFS just an interface/common language that the file system drivers must implement, and in reality the Application is talking directly with the file systems drivers using this interface/common language?

Answer (score 7):

The VFS is an interface layer in the kernel. It provides a uniform interface for applications to talk to file systems, regardless of the file system in use: thus system calls such as `open`, `write`, `read` all go to the VFS layer, which then dispatches them to the appropriate file system.

File systems register themselves with the VFS layer and provide a standard set of information, so that the VFS layer can use them. This means that all file systems in Linux need to implement similar concepts: mainly inodes, directory entries, and files.

This is [documented in detail in the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt).

Answer (score 3):

VFS is an entire software layer in the kernel situated between the system calls and the filesystem drivers, it is not a filesystem in its own right.

It provides a common **interface** to multiple file system types.

Imagine for example we use the command:

```
cp /usb/file /tmp/file
```

`/usb` is mounted on a fat32 USB, `/tmp` is a `etx2` filesytem.

VFS layer sits between the application and the file system, so the `cp` command does not need to know the file system in which is it performing the copy. Instead `cp` interacts with VFS using generic system calls eg: `open`,`write`,`read` etc....

Answer (score 0):

Interface, and common functionality.

## Interface

File-systems need to implement the interface

## Common functionality

There are some things that all file-systems would have to implement, but the implementations would be the same. E.g. caching, symlink traversal.

(Note I have not worked on it, so may have a few errors)