# Host's VFS and Docker's OverlayFS

Tags: docker, overlayfs, vfs

Linux's Virtual File System(VFS) provides a common interface to multiple file system types, for example, ext2, ext3, VFAT, etc.

Imagine an ubuntu host is running several docker containers, and the storage driver of docker is [OverlayFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/).

[image]

What's the relation between the ubuntu host's VFS and Docker's OverlayFS?

Which tier does OverlayFS belong to?

Does it belong to Application, or at the same level as VFS?

### Reference

[Is the Virtual File System (VFS) a program or is it just an interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437285/is-the-virtual-file-system-vfs-a-program-or-is-it-just-an-interface)

Answer (score 0):

It is in the kernel at the same level as ext2, interfaced via the VFS.
Remember, docker uses the same kernel. The processes run the same as non-docker processes, just different permissions.